# Visual Studio 2012 UI: QuickFind disappeared?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012RC, I am trying to bring back **QuickFind**, which was correctly working up to the moment I unfortunately decided to use the *Find in Files* functionality.

Now pressing CTRL+F or CTR+shift+F will, in both cases, bring up the *Find and Replace [Find In Files, Replace In Files]* window.
I temporary managed to add the "Switch to Quick Find" toolbar icon, which worked once.
But now even that does not work.

I have tried to remove the keyboard shortcut to *Find in Files* and *QuickFind* and reassign the one to QuickFind, but it does not help.

Same if I use QuickLaunch: regardless I select *QuickFind* or *Find In Files*, I always get *Find In Files*.

Any idea apart re-installing the whole application?

**EDIT**

This seem to happen only for a specific file. If I bring up a different file in the editor, Ctrl+F will bring up **QuickFind**. It looks like it is storing somewhere the search method and that is overriding the QuickFind. Very confusing. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: A duplicated superuser question have imho a current better answer: http://superuser.com/questions/477824/find-in-files-instead-of-find-invoked-in-visual-studio-2012-on-sql-type-file There is a link to a connect bug report acknowledged and fixed by Microsoft

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Understood what is the issue.
Ctrl+F will not bring up QuickFind when the document window is in split mode.

Must be a bug of VS2012.

Comment: Worse, if the Quick Find window is open in a Split mode SQL code window, closing the split pane where the Quick Find window is docked may cause it to permanently disappear, or for the Find in Files window to appear instead of the Quick Find.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that some file types do not support the quick find feature (which is probably a bug).  I found that *.SQL file types do not allow the quick find, whereas *.cs works just fine.  As a test:

1. I created a TextFile1.TXT file in my solution and it works with quick find.
2. I renamed the file to TextFile1.SQL and the quick find doesn't appear.  You get the full find dialog instead

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug, which Microsoft wont fix :(

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769189/ctrl-f-opens-find-in-files-rather-than-find

Comment: In this bug report, they simply have miss understood the issue. But they hav acknowledge it and fixed in an other one : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759133/attempting-to-open-the-quick-find-dialog-when-a-sql-file-has-focus-opens-the-find-in-files-dialog

Comment: That one says closed and fixed, but I still see it in my version of 2012 :(

Comment: The fix requires to install a recent version of SSDT. (No, it is not fixed through a VS update, but by installing an other set of tools over.) Have you done that ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is recreating the file - just creating a new file in the same location, copying and pasting the content of the file affecting, saving and disposing of the original file does the trick.
In the new file Quick Find and Find in Files will both work correctly.

Not sure if this a bug of Visual Studio 2012, posting the reply here so that someone else has not to waste all this time.

Comment: Is this still fixed after saving the new file as .sql?